# how to handle day light saving?

Tags: sql-server-2008

I wrote a window service (C#) which continuously pull the data from Oracle Database to Sql Server Database.

Window service runs in infinite loop and take a sleep for i minute after one successful run.

Every run of window service, I treat as Job and for that Job No I am passing 2 input date/time parameter to oracle SP which fetch all the records between 2 date passed,

Here the logic for passing dates,

[image]

Now, in day light saving mode, I clock is forwarded by some hour ahead, then I am loosing data for that period.

How to handle this day light saving scenario, I am generating start/end date from below sql queries,

```
DECLARE @startDate VARCHAR(20)
DECLARE @endDate VARCHAR(20)

IF EXISTS(SELECT 1 FROM dbo.tblImportAlertsJob(NOLOCK) WHERE JobStatus = 'Completed')
BEGIN
    SELECT @startDate = CONVERT(VARCHAR, DATEADD(ss, 1, InputEndDateTime), 112) + ' ' + CONVERT(VARCHAR, DATEADD(ss, 1, InputEndDateTime), 8)
    FROM dbo.tblImportAlertsJob(NOLOCK)
    WHERE JobID  = (SELECT MAX(JobID) FROM dbo.tblImportAlertsJob(NOLOCK) WHERE JobStatus = 'Completed')
END
ELSE
BEGIN
    SELECT @startDate = CONVERT(VARCHAR, DATEADD(ss, -60, GETDATE()), 112) + ' ' + CONVERT(VARCHAR, DATEADD(ss, -60, GETDATE()), 8)
END

SET @endDate = CONVERT(VARCHAR, GETDATE(), 112) + ' ' + CONVERT(VARCHAR, GETDATE(), 8)

INSERT INTO dbo.tblImportAlertsJob(InputStartDateTime, InputEndDateTime) VALUES(@startDate, @endDate)

SELECT CAST(SCOPE_IDENTITY() AS BIGINT) AS 'JobId', @startDate AS 'StartDate', @endDate AS 'EndDate'
```

Comment: `in day light saving mode, I clock is forwarded 2 hour ahead` ... I know of no country where the time changes by 2 hours during daylight savings time.

Comment: OP edited... I think by 2.30 hrs

Comment: The simple approach is to use UTC time, which doesn't jump.